# Use $map in MongoDb queries

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to use the `$map` operator in a regular Mongo document query (or aggregate `$match` which I believe is the same thing).

What I'm trying to do is thus: Given an set of sets, return the document if any of the sets is a subset of a parameter.

Example:

Let's say I have three documents:

```
{ x : [ ["A","B"] ] }
{ x : [ ["A", "D"] ] }
{ x : [ ["A","B"], ["A","D"] ] }
```

and I have an array

```
auths = ["A","B","C"]
```

I want to run a query where I get back the first and third documents because both contain the set `["A","B"]` which is a subset of `auths`, but not the second document because its only set contains `D` which is not in the set of `auths`

If I were doing this in a `$redact` pipeline I could do this with something along the lines of:

```
{"$anyElementTrue" : {
    "$map" : { 
       "input": "$x",
       "as": "s",
       "in": { "$setIsSubset": ["$$s", auths] }
    }
 }}
```

but when I try to run this as a query I get

```
BadValue unknown top level operator: $anyElementTrue
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in a `$match` stage or a find query. You will need to use a `$project` stage to add a field you can `$match` on:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "ok" : { "$map" : { "input" : "$x", "as" : "s", "in" : { "$setIsSubset" : [ "$$s", auths] } } }
    } },
    { "$match" : { "ok" : true } }
])
```

You can adjust the `$project` to include whatever other fields from the original document.

Comment: That seems silly.  So If I have 200,000,000 documents in my db, and only 20 of them would have passed the criteria, I'm going to generate 200,000,000 documents in the `$project` pipeline, which I'll then have to go through again just to match 20 documents??

Comment: @FuriousGeorge I'm concerned with this same point. Did you find any better solution?